# How to calculate overlap week in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

By using date object how we can calculate over lapping weeks?

For eg:

July 31(Tuesday) is end for the week number 38, However week number 38 ends Sunday i.e Aug 4.

However months are different

Any idea on this

Thanks all

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to calculate for overlapping weeks. Do you just want to give a date; and then "output' the last day of the week? (Saturday?)

Comment: No not only just date, Need show week number along with dates in a month. for Eg week 38, July 29 to July 31 is for Month July 2012. However Aug 1 to Aug 4 of 2012 also comes into same week number i.e 38. So these dates are overlapping, as they belongs 2 different month

Comment: I modified my answer with information on how to get the weekOfYear, the firstDate of that week, and the last date of that week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our Calendar component, we use this code to calculate the first date in a week; and I bet it could be modified to find the last Date of the Week.  IT makes use of the [DateUtils library](http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/)

```
    public static const DAY_OF_MONTH:String = "date";

    /**
     * This method gets the first date of the week which the given date is in.
     * 
     * @param date  This is the date for which we want to process.
     * @param firstDayOfWeek    The first day of the week, 0 (Sunday) - 6 (Saturday); 0 is the default.  It will probably be used primarily for localization purposes.
     * 
     * @return      This returns a date representing the first day of the week.
     */
    public static function firstDateOfWeek( date:Date, firstDayOfWeek : int = 0 ):Date {
        var dayIncrement : int = dayOfWeekLocalized(date, firstDayOfWeek);

        var returnDate : Date = DateUtils.dateAdd(DateUtils.DAY_OF_MONTH,-dayIncrement,date);
        return returnDate; 

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the position of the day in a week, with respect to the firstDayOfWeek localization variable. 
     * 
     * If firstDayOfWeek is 0; then the week is display 0 (Sunday), 1 (Monday), 2 (Tuesday), 3 (Wednesday), 4 (Thursday), 5 (Friday), 6 (Saturday).  
     * So, a Sunday would return 0, a Saturday would return 6, and so on.  
     * 
     * If firstDayOfWeek is 1; then the week is displayed as 0 (Monday), 1 (Tuesday), 2 (Wednesday), 3 (Thursday), 4 (Friday), 5 (Saturday), 6 (Sunday). 
     * However, this situation will not change the date.day value.  For display purposes we need a Sunday to return 6, a Saturday to return 5, and so on.
     * 
     * This will presumably be used for display purposes.
     * 
     * @param date  This is the date to process.
     * @param firstDayOfWeek    The first day of the week, 0 (Sunday) - 6 (Saturday); 0 is the default.  It will probably be used primarily for localization purposes.
     * 
     * @return      This returns a date representing the day’s location on the localized week display.
     */
    public static function dayOfWeekLocalized( date:Date, firstDayOfWeek : int = 0 ):int {
        var result : int = date.day - firstDayOfWeek;
        if(result < 0){
            result += 7;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

To find the last date of a week, I suspect you can just call the firstDateOfWeek and add 6 days:

```
    public static function lastDateOfWeek( date:Date, firstDayOfWeek : int = 0 ):Date {
        var firstDateOfWeek : Date = firstDateOfWeek(date, firstDayOfWeek);

        var returnDate : Date = DateUtils.dateAdd(DateUtils.DAY_OF_MONTH,6,firstDateOfWeek );
        return returnDate; 
    }
```

Note: The second batch of code was written in a browser and is completely untested.

---

Update:
Given a specific date, you can find out the weekOfYear number using the weekOfYear method in the [DateUtils library](http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/).  Use the methods above to find the first and last date of the week in question

Conceptually like this:

```
var weekOfYear : Number = DateUtils.weekOfYear(myDate);
var firstDayOfWeek : Date = firstDateOfWeek(myDate);
var lastDayOfWeek : Date = lastDateOfWeek(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this very question in [this blog post](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/05/working-with-dates-in-as3.html). It's very simple, really. The last day of any given month is one day less than the first day of the next month. If the last day isn't a Saturday, you have an overlap.

Comment: Does the original poster want to know whether the week in question spans two months?  Or does he want to know what the actual last day of the week is?  I was unclear.  This would answer the first question.